# ASP.NET Controls are not coming in Code-behind IntelliSense

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, code-behind

I am having an aspx page where I have added one asp.net text box control with ID and RUNAT attribute. But in Code-behind I am not seeing this control's name in the intellisense.

My page directive in aspx is as follows

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProject_UI._Default" %>
```

I am using VS 2008. Any idea how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `CodeFile` instead of `CodeBehind`.  The latter is a hold-over from .NET 1.1.

Also, make sure the namespaces match up between the markup and the code.  Do a test compile to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this on occasion when I edit a page.  When it happens to me, I close the files and open them again and it seems to fix itself.

Answer (score 2):

This will happen if you are trying to include your control in LayoutTemplate. For example if you are using an asp label in a login control you have converted to a LayoutTemplate.

```
<asp:Login ID="userLogin" runat="server">
   <LayoutTemplate>
     <!--Username and password controls-->
     <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" CommandName="Login" runat="server" Text="Login" />
     <asp:Label ID="lblAlert" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </LayoutTemplate>
```

So your lblAlert will not show up on the code behind take it out of the layouttemplate or use a loop to find the control within the layout object.

```
var mylabel = (Label)userLogin.FindControl("lblAlert");
```